# How to unit test the code of a web worker in Angular9+

Tags: angular, jasmine, web-worker

I have a very simple web worker (you can see its code below).

```html
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

    export class MyWorker {

        constructor() {
          this.initWorkerListener();
        }

        add(x: number, y: number): number {
          return x + y;
        }

        initWorkerListener = (): void => {
            addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
                const result = this.add(data.x, data.y);
                postMessage(result);
            });

        }
    }

    const worker = new MyWorker();
```

I want to write a spec.ts in an Angular project to test that code.
I tried the way I run all the Angular tests, but it didn't work.

Any ideas on how to do this?